# Upload files by form using node.js

Tags: html, node.js

So I'm trying to upload files by using form in static html file and node.js server. Server load my static HTML file and also respond - there are no errors, but files don't upload. Below are my files. Maybe they lack something?

Node.js file:

```
var http = require("http");
var qs = require("querystring")
var fs = require("fs");
var formidable = require('formidable');  

var server = http.createServer(function(req,response){        

    switch (req.method) {
        case "GET":
            fs.readFile("static/index01.html", function (error, data) {        
                if (error) {
                    response.writeHead(404, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
                    response.write("<h1>błąd 404 - file dosen't exiist!<h1>");
                    response.end();
                }
        
                else {
                    response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
                    response.write(data);
                    response.end();
                }
            });

            break;

        case "POST":
            function servResponse(){

                let form = formidable({})

                form.uploadDir = "/static/upload/"
                
                form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
                    response.writeHead(200, { 'content-type': 'text/plain;charset=utf-8' });
                    response.end("file uploaded");
                });
            }
            servResponse(req, response)

        break;

} 
})

server.listen(3000, function(){
   console.log("server start on 3000 port")
});
```

And body HTML file - index01.html:

```
<body>


    <form method="POST">
        <input type="file">
        <button type="submit"> upload</button>
    </form>
    
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

- A form control (including any `input`) can't be successful (and upload data) without a `name`
- A form can't upload files with the (default) `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoding, you need to use the `enctype` attribute to explicitly specify that the form should use the `multipart/form-data` encoding.

Comment: Thank you, it works now! Sorry for stupid mistakes but I just started my journey with node.js :)